# Picture element not choosing file it should

Tags: html, css, image

I have a simple picture element that should be display one of two pictures depending on the browser window size:

```
  <picture>
    <source src="images/still_life-650_medium_2x.jpg" media="max-width:899px" type="image/jpeg">
    <source src="images/still_life-1600_large_2x.jpg" media="min-width:900px" type="image/jpeg">
    <img src="images/still_life-1600_large_2x.jpg" alt="Old calculator and some fruit">
  </picture>
```

However when I test it with the browser sized below 899px, no matter how small I resize it in fact, it always loads the "images/still_life-1600_large_2x.jpg" file (Using Chrome devtools to determine what file it is loading as the image looks the same).

Is there something wrong with the above code?

Comment: did you try doing it like this: `srcset="..." media="(max-width: 899px)"` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture

Comment: @Deryck That did it! The srcset and the () around the max-width. Thank you.

Comment: excellent glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Deryck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2780033/deryck) answered it in his comment.

```
   <picture>
    <source srcset="images/still_life-650_medium_2x.jpg" media="(max-width:899px)" type="image/jpeg">
    <source srcset="images/still_life-1600_large_2x.jpg" media="(min-width:900px)" type="image/jpeg">
    <img src="images/still_life-1600_large_2x.jpg" alt="Old calculator and some fruit">
  </picture>
```